# using cout to print an string array not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string, rubiks-cube

I have this code, which is supposed to cout an string of an array, but it doesn't do anything :/
also, when I run the .exe file itself it gives some errors of not finding basic_string in the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//red is F-face, yellow is D-face
//B G O R W Y

class cube{
    public:
        string cubeCorners[8] = {"BOY", "GOY", "GRY", "BRY", "BOW", "GOW", "GRW", "BRW"};

        void U(){
            cout << cubeCorners[1];
            cubeCorners[2] = cubeCorners[3], cubeCorners[6] = cubeCorners[2], cubeCorners[7] = cubeCorners[6], cubeCorners[3] = cubeCorners[7];
        }
};

int main(){
    cube obj;
    obj.U();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this, and what did I do wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted prints "GOY". What did you expect it to do exactly?

Comment: Please paste in your actual error messages. We can't interpret "vague"

Comment: What are the assignments in the comma list supposed to do. Put them on sepearte lines with ; They do exactly the same.

Comment: What output exactly do you get?

Comment: Arrays start at 0

Comment: it is going to be a program to solve a Rubik's cube with the beginners method, I just wanted a challenge. GOY refers to the Green-Orange-Yellow corner of the cube. There are no error messages in the terminal and no red lines in the code itself.

Comment: when I open the .exe it give an error, not in cmd, that says Couldn't find accesspoint of procedure _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ in DLL-file D:\c++workspace\rubiks cube\cube.exe

Comment: the assingments in the comma list are supposed to be switched with each other, these represent the corner pieces of the cube on the front side, and the function will rotate this side clockwise.

Comment: What are you _expecting_ to happen with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years ago when I was using MinGW, I got exactly the same kind of problem as you did. Whenever the code used any C++ standard library function, it could compile, but could not run.

The problem was due to libstdc++ being installed incorrectly. A quick fix is to add `-static-libstdc++` to your compiler option. However, to fully resolve the issue you have to reinstall your compiler and standard library.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow as soon as possible, because this is not the first time I got this  kind of problem. Maybe it will fix my other programs too, as there are alot of weird things like this happening and I am sick of it. Thanks alot!

Comment: well, I tried the quick fix, but it doesn't seem to work, I am using visual studio code, in the user settings it now says this:{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "clang.cxxflags": ["-static-libstdc++"]
}

Comment: what do you mean with reinstalling compiler and standard library? Reinstalling minGW? or do I have to download from somewhere else?

Comment: I use gcc. -static-libstdc++ is a gcc specific option, requiring the compiler to link libstdc++ at compile time, instead of run time. I don't know about the corresponding command for clang.

Comment: Delete the whole MinGW folder, and run the installer again should work.